# How can i add autolayout programatically to a background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have programatically set an image to a UIViewController background. How can i add autolayout programatically so it gets displayed both in iPad and iPhone?

The code is below:

```
UIImageView *bkImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bkImage.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:bkImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Create the necessary constraint using one of the `NSLayoutConstraint` class methods that give you a constraint.

2) Add it to the view using the `UIview's` methods for adding a constraint.

Comment: Can you show me an example. Sorry but i am new to this.

Comment: The examples are in the UIView and NSLayoutConstraint class reference documentation.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/

Answer (score 0):

This adds constraints of 0 leading, 0 trailing, 0 top and 0 bottom. You can modify them as per your needs.

```
[bkImage setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bkImage
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:self.view
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                      multiplier:1.0f
                                                        constant:0.0f]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bkImage
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                     multiplier:1.0f
                                                       constant:0.0f]];



[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bkImage
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:self.view
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                      multiplier:1.0f
                                                        constant:0.0f]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bkImage
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:self.view
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      multiplier:1.0f
                                                        constant:0.0f]];
```